# Setting image from database

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am trying to get the image stored in the MYSQL database and set it on a JSP page, but I am getting the following error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [SearchStudentControlling] in context
>   with path [/Roomantech] threw exception
>   [java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() contain error so i
>   didn,t the image in my jsp page

I am using the following code to get and set the image. I am getting the error on line number 339 which doesn't exist (my code has only 312 lines). I have been struggling for last two hours but couldn't pinpoint the problem.

```
    session = request.getSession(false);
        if(session!=null)
        {
              %>

 <div style="width:100%;height:70%;">
  <%@include file="header.jsp"%>

  <div align="center" style="margin-top:150px">
  <table align="center" width="73%;" height="100%;" class="abc">
    <form action="nextpersonalinformation.do" method="post">
                <strong><h2 style="color: darkblue;margin-bottom:30px;"><b><u>Person Information****</b></u></h2></strong>

           <tr><td></td><td></td></tr> 
           <tr style="background-color: #003366;color: white;border-radius:5px"><td><h4 style="color: darkblue"><b style="color: white"> Your Hostel details****:</b></h4></td><td><b style="color: white">Enter Values:</b></td></tr> 

             <tr><td></td><td></td></tr> 
             <tr style="background-color: teal;font-size: 20px"></tr>

            <%                 

            ArrayList<PersonDetaildto>pa = (ArrayList<PersonDetaildto>)session.getAttribute("InformationPerson");
                for(PersonDetaildto kk : pa)
                {

                 System.out.println(kk.getFirst_nm()+" "+kk.getMiddle_nm());
            %>
                <tr>
             <td>Person Image</td>
             <td><img height="75px" width="75px" align="left" src="
              <% byte[] imgbytes = kk.getPerson_image();
                        InputStream images  =  kk.getPersonimagee();
                        int size1=0;  
                        response.reset();  
                        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");  
                        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","filename=logo.jpg");  
                        while((size1=images.read(imgbytes))!= -1 )  
                          {  
                            response.getOutputStream().write(imgbytes,0,size1);  
                          }  
                        response.flushBuffer(); 
                       images.close();  


             %>"/></td>
             </tr>
               <tr><td></td><td></td></tr> 
             <tr><td></td><td></td></tr> 
             <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>

              <tr>
          </table>

     </div>
     <div style="width:100%;height:200px;">
     </div>

     <% 
                }

     }
        else
        {
            response.sendRedirect("welcome.do");
        }

     %>

    <%@include file="footer.jsp"%>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you somehow saving the image in your database?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
You cannot add images by inserting the bytes into HTML (as Funtik already pointed out).
But you can insert it by converting your image-bytes into **Base64**:

```
<img alt="YourEmbeddedImage" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgkAAAJNCAIAAAA0yXHVAAAACXBIWXMA..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Ben pointed out, you can output the bytes of an image inside your src tag by encoding it in base64.

But still, I advice you to use another solution for your problem.

A better solution would be to store the images on the hard drive, but keep the filenames inside the database. In this case your solution would be something like:

```
<td>Person Image</td>
<td><img height="75px" width="75px" align="left" src="<%  kk.getPersonimagee() %>"></td>
```

Comment: @Ben, your example does not answer the question :)

Comment: @funtik   I get the url of the image in jsp page but i didn,t get the image on jsp page